# "undefined reference to *" Error while compiling file that uses the Open Dynamics Engine v0.13.1

Tags: c++, installation, ode-library

I am a beginner to organizing C++ projects and I have been trying to start an Open Dynamics Engine project for a week now but I keep getting several errors. First, what I have done:

- Installed ode-0.13.1 with automake as directed in the [manual](http://ode.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual).
- Created a file `test.cpp` with the code from the [bouncing ball HOWTO](http://ode.org/wiki/index.php?title=Simple_Bouncing_Sphere).
- Wrote a makefile to compile.

But when I run my makefile, I get the following errors:

> gcc -Wall -g -DdDOUBLE -o test test.o -L/home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/libode.la -L/home/username/ode-0.13.1/drawstuff/src/libdrawstuff.la -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -I. -I/home/username/ode-0.13.1/include/ -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include -lm -lode -lGL -lGLU
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(collision_trimesh_box.o): In function `dCalcVectorLength3':
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/../../include/ode/odemath.h:148: undefined reference to`sqrt'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/../../include/ode/odemath.h:148: undefined reference to `sqrt'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/../../include/ode/odemath.h:148: undefined reference to`sqrt'
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(util.o): In function `dxStepBody(dxBody*, double)':
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/util.cpp:618: undefined reference to`sincos'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/util.cpp:630: undefined reference to `sincos'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/util.cpp:628: undefined reference to`sqrt'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/ode/src/util.cpp:590: undefined reference to `sqrt'

... (and this keeps going for pages)

> /usr/local/lib/libode.a(OPC_AABBTree.o): In function `Opcode::AABBTree::Build(Opcode::AABBTreeBuilder*)':
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/OPCODE/OPC_AABBTree.cpp:413: undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned long)'
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/OPCODE/OPC_AABBTree.cpp:427: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(OPC_AABBTree.o): In function`Opcode::AABBTreeNode::~AABBTreeNode()':
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/OPCODE/OPC_AABBTree.cpp:83: undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*, unsigned long)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(OPC_Collider.o): In function`Opcode::Collider::~Collider()':
>   /home/username/ode-0.13.1/OPCODE/OPC_Collider.cpp:54: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(OPC_Collider.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6Opcode8ColliderE[_ZTIN6Opcode8ColliderE]+0x0): undefined reference to`vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
>   /usr/local/lib/libode.a(OPC_Collider.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6Opcode8ColliderE[_ZTVN6Opcode8ColliderE]+0x20): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   makefile:14: recipe for target 'test' failed
>   make: *** [test] Error 1

These errors seem like the library has not been set up correctly, but I'm pretty sure I've properly installed and my -L's are set to the correct paths.

Note 1: the demos included with the ode library work.

Note 2: I've tried (and failed) to install other versions of ode previously. I  did my best with `make uninstall` and `make clean` to clean these failed installs, but I think they may be affecting new installs because when I run `sudo make install` for the first time there is an awful lot of `Nothing to do here...` messages.

Comment: Try putting `-lm` last. `-lode -lGL -lGLU -lm`. Order matters.

Comment: Also use g++ not gcc for C++ code.

Comment: FYI it's pretty typical to install custom libs of yours into the `/usr/local` prefix (run `configure` with `--prefix=/usr/local`) so that your installs are cleanly overlaid on top of anything that your OS installed (and can be cleanly destroyed in the event that you want to delete everything you manually installed without adversely affecting your OS)